# How does make finds the order of modules?

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile with content like this

```
MODULES =  ADW AEG DLG FDUfinance ODD PRI SPPA ADFGcommon PYMT LUR LBD \
           FAA PPTP COLLINT COR ADFG COA COLLINTtestRecord COLLINTtestScenario \
           LFPL LFP
include $(CORE)/BUILD/package.mk
```

When I give `make` how does it finds the order ADW, AEG.. and builds one after the other?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question.  The `package.mk` file will, presumably, contain some make rules that describe how the contents of `MODULES` will be built and define the order.

Comment: Partial answer - it "finds the order ADW, AEG.." because that's what is explicitly specified - it goes with the order assigned in the `MODULES` variable. How it builds each of them though, @MadScientist is right - there's no way to tell without the contents of `package.mk` and possibly some other things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I give make how does it finds the order ADW, AEG.. and builds one after the other?

hmm , well yeah but not exactly like that ..... I completely agree with @madscientist and @twalberg observations.

have a look at the example makefile :

```
Kaizen ~/make_prac $ cat mk.name
 ## make to accept name and display hello name
 arg1="" ;

 .PHONY : name \
  hello

   hello : name
         echo "hello $(arg1)" ;

    name :
          echo "name given is : $(arg1)" ;
```

here once the make reads the makefile(descriptor file) , it is then able to form a dependency tree .... like whats dependent/required for what. so internally it makes a has something like this...

```
  hello <-- name <-- no dep 
  name <-- no dep
```

this is based on the content of the makefile -- the rules/targets (hello and name are rules here) and their dependency list ( files/targets after the : )

so from the line

```
   hello : name
           echo "hello $(arg1)" ;
```

it can imply that to build the target hello , the target name needs to be available/build first. likewise it will go through each and every target mentioned and its dependency list , making a "overall build" chain(you can also refer to it as a dependency tree) in the process.... as mentioned above.

for execution it always refers to the build chain and builds the dependencies for a target(if they are out of date) before building the target itself

output of example :

```
   Kaizen ~/make_prac $ make -f mk.name arg1="kaizen" ;
     echo "name given is : kaizen" ;
     name given is : kaizen
     echo "hello kaizen" ;
     hello kaizen
```

Now back to your question :

MODULES =  ADW AEG DLG FDUfinance ODD PRI SPPA ADFGcommon PYMT LUR LBD \
           FAA PPTP COLLINT COR ADFG COA COLLINTtestRecord COLLINTtestScenario \
           LFPL LFP
include $(CORE)/BUILD/package.mk

here Module is not a target but a variable which i suppose somewhere below in your makefile gets substituted into a rule..... chk for occurence of $(MODULE)

but there is no accurate way to say ADW will be build before AEG .... as in your makefile iff a rule might state AEG as a dependent for the target ADW , then to build ADW make will have to build AEG first thus adding to its build chain ADW <-- AEG.

hence reversing your assumption.... Does this help you understand the chaining process ?

if you are still a bit confused ...... visit the link `http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/make_inhalt.en.html`

this should explain you most of the concepts in about 5-7 mins...

hope this helps !